# VSCode VIM Extension - E488 Trailing Characters

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscodevim

I'm trying to insert a range using:

```
:put =range(11,15)
```

But the error: E488: trailing characters appears. How can I resolve this issue? I am using the VIM extension for VSCode.